# $.extend with excluding some JSON objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, extend

please refer below code.

```
var series=$.extend({},true,options,this.model.series);
```

this will merge all JSON objects from options to this.model.series. i want to exclude single JSON object from merging options with this.model.series

```
options:{style:{},points:[{},{}], marker:{},...}
```

i want to merge or copy all json objects from options to this.model.series **`except points`**.

because for 10,000 points it takes long time to merge all json objects with this.model.series this will degrades the performance.

how can i improve the performance by efficiently using $.extend ( may be points merging takes too much time). how can i do for this case ?

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: why can't you make `options["points"] = null` before running `extend`?

Comment: no we can't make points null.because we need points collection

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I think you are using $.extend incorrectly. Your true parameter should be the first parameter for doing recursion. Secondly, I don't think there is any way to extend-exclude with jQuery.extend(). Try this:

```
var series = {};
$.each(options,function(key,value){
  if( key != 'points' )
    series[key] = value;
});
$.extend(true,series,this.model.series);
```

That is the lazy way. That way you can include a check for other keys (not just 'points'). If that isn't fast enough then you should create recursion within that function and extend the object manually instead of having to use jQuery extend after.

or this, to re-include new points after the extend:

```
var points = options.points;
options.points = null;
series = $.extend(true,options,this.model.series);
series.points = points;
```

**Edit after comment to preserver points:**

```
var tempOptions = options, tempSeries = this.model.series;
tempOptions.points = null;
tempSeries.points = null;
var series = $.extend(true,tempOptions,tempSeries);
series.points = options.points; // Use this one OR
series.points = this.model.series.points; // Use this one, depending on what you need
```

**Further effort:**

```
var series = {}, tempSeries = {};
$.each(options,function(key,value){
  if( key != 'points' )
    series[key] = value;
});
$.each(this.model.series,function(key,value){
  if( key != 'points' )
    tempSeries[key] = value;
});
$.extend(true,series,tempSeries);
series.points = this.model.series.points;
```

**Custom implementation:**

```
function extendExclude( exclude, obj1, obj2 ) {
    for( i in obj2 ) {
        if( ( typeof obj1[i] !== 'object' ) || ( typeof obj2[i] !== 'object' ) ) {
            obj1[i] = obj2[i];
        } else if( i != exclude ) {
            extendExclude( null, obj1[i], obj2[i] )
        }
    }
    return obj1;
}

var series = extendExclude( 'points', options, this.model.series );
```

This could be extended to include infinite objs as parameter to extend & to include an array of exclude options; but not in this version :)

Comment: i can't able to set points=null. because we need that points. i just need don't want to merge this points with series i  want to merge only other properties instead of points

Comment: @precastc you are wrong when you using var temp=options and then set null temp.points=null will set options.points=null too.

Comment: @SivaRajini Yes you are right... I will work on something else :)

Comment: @SivaRajini Try the further effort or custom implementation

Comment: thanks will check and let you know. once again thanks for your efforts